# Using QComboBox with available cameras Qml PyQt5

Tags: qml, repeater, pyqt5

I'm just starting to learn about PyQT5 and Qml in general.

I have the following code:

```js
ListView {
         anchors.fill: parent
         model: QtMultimedia.availableCameras
         delegate: Text {
            text: modelData.displayName

            MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: camera.deviceId = modelData.deviceId
            }
         }
}
```

Which displays the available cameras in a list view. What I am trying to do is display them in a ComboBox instead.

What I would like to do is display the availableCameras in a ComboBox as such:

```js
ComboBox {
     anchors.fill: parent
     model: QtMultimedia.availableCameras
}
```

However, the QtMultimedia.availableCameras returns an array of objects and I would like to enumerate them all and get their display names.

I have looked into Repeater.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can do the same as in list: `delegate: Text {
            text: modelData.displayName }`? Or `textRole:"displayName"`.

Comment: I tried this but I get the error "Cannot assign to non-existent property "delegate""

Comment: Ok, you didn't noticed what QtQuick.Controls version do you use. `delegate` is for 2 only, For 1.4 and latter use `textRole`

Comment: Thanks! This helped in the end!